# using sum in flexible type array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a flexible type array such that the first column is a node number and the next three are 3D coordinates like this `M=np.array([(0,1.1,2.1,3.1),(1,4,5,6),(2,10,11,12)],dtype=[('N','i4'),('x','f8'),('y','f8'),('z','f8')])`:

```
>>> array([(0,  1.1,  2.1,  3.1), 
           (1,  4. ,  5. ,  6. ),
           (2, 10. , 11. , 12. )],
           dtype=[('N', '<i4'), ('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
```

Now I would like to get a vector that is the sum of each column for 'x','y' and 'z'. Naively it would be something like: `M[['x','y','z']].sum()` but that gives the error: `TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type`

My actual example is slightly more complicated because I have a list of elements with nodes: `E=np.array([[0,1],[1,2]])` and what I want is the sum of the coordinates of the nodes for each element. I can do this for each dimension like this: `M[E]['x'].sum(axis=0)` that gives `array([5.1,14])`.

Is there a way to do it with all dimensions at the same type such that I end up with the same as `M=np.array([(5.1,7.1,9.1),(14,16,18),],dtype=[('x','f8'),('y','f8'),('z','f8')])`, i.e.

```
array([( 5.1,  7.1,  9.1), 
       (14. , 16. , 18. )],
       dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
```

Comment: That is a structured array with one dimension. It doesn't have "columns", which might clear up some confusion.

Comment: For math like this, it is better to use numeric dtype arrays, e.g. a 1d array for `N`, and a 2d (n,3) array for the float coordinate values.  With the structured array you are stuck with acting on each field by name.  As the error indicates, math like operations are not defined for a compound dtype.

Comment: A typical structured array has many elements (rows) and just a few named fields, e.g. (1000,) shape, with 3 fields.  Iteration over the 3 fields to perform an action like `sum` over the 1000 elements is relatively cheap.  If that doesn't describe your case, I'd suggest reevaluating the use of structure arrays.

Comment: That covers my case. I have thousands of elements and nodes and each of them has only a small number of fields. Regarding using the arrays separately the problem is that I have multiple fields and I want to be able to use different data types and keep the structure together when I do operations like sorting or exporting.